# why does ListBox populate individual characters from (.edmx) model on new line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-5, edmx

I am trying to populate a listbox from a model which is my Entity framework edmx model I seems to be populating but each character is appearing on a new line so for instance

H 

A

L

O

instead of

HALO

this is my controller:

```
private dataEntities dbGame = new dataEntities();

[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        dbdata dbdata = new dbdata();
        List<SelectListItem> listSelectItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (dbdata dbdata in dbGame.dbdata)
        {
            SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem();
            {
                selectList.Text = dbdata.GameTitle;
                selectList.Value = dbdata.GameId;
            };

            dbdata.GameTitle = selectList.Text;
            dbdata.Value = selectList.Value;


            listSelectItems.Add(selectList);
        }

        return View(dbdata);

    }
```

razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.ListBox(Model.GameTitle, new SelectList(Model.GameTitle));
}
```

any suggestions as to why it's doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because GameTitle property is type of string(a sequence of characters).
so, try like this:

```
ViewBag.items = listSelectItems;
return View(dbdata);
```

in your View:

```
 @Html.ListBox(Model.GameTitle,(IEnumerable<SelectListItems>)ViewBag.items)
```

you don't need:

```
        dbdata.GameTitle = selectList.Text;
        dbdata.Value = selectList.Value;
```

Or you can put a property of type `List<SelectListItem>` in your dbdata model, then assign listSelectItems to it then `return View(dbdata);`.

Comment: thanks, that worked. Also do you know how I can move the data in this lisrview to another listview I can create a new question if you like

Comment: i don't get it, can you explain?